# Which place in Europe and/or Russia had its catenary lines removed/replaced several times for political reasons?

Tags: germany, soviet-union, poland

I could swear I remember reading about a city or rail line -- maybe in Germany? Maybe in Poland? -- that had the overhead electrical wires for trains removed, exported to another city or country, and then eventually replaced more than once over the course of a few decades, thanks to changes in who had political control. I believe some of it had to do with the USSR becoming the controlling entity for a time and wanting to centralize resources in the Russian part of the union. This may have also involved the Nazi regime and whatever government came to power after the USSR collapsed, if I remember correctly.

Does anyone know where this is? (Link, please.)

Comment: (East) Germany certainly had a lot of railway equipment removed and shipped to the USSR as reparations after the Second World War but reparations were paid at most once per railway line (and not all was rebuilt). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure I read (most likely on Wikipedia) about a town or region where it happened more than once.

Comment: (I am not the same Jan who commented above): Here are two places where removing the overhead lines might have happened twice, once by Soviets and once by thieves:  https://www.sueddeutsche.de/panorama/bahn-oberleitung-gestohlen-diebe-scheuten-weder-gefahr-noch-gewicht-1.961931, https://www.thueringen24.de/thueringen/article212642025/Teile-der-Oberleitung-geklaut-Massive-Zugprobleme-in-Thueringen.html?service=amp